# mgt-react PeoplePicker defaultSelectedUsers not working as I would expect

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I've been writing a React app that relies on the mgt-react components.

The app is basically just an interface to a SharePoint library.

Everything has been working great and the PeoplePicker is working in so much as I can start typing a users name and the drop down works and I can select a person.

However now I'm at the point where I want to create an edit screen. In order to implement this I need to prepopulate the PeoplePicker with the users that were input at insert time.

I can't seem to get the "defaultSelectedUsers" property to work.

I've pared things down to simply hardcoding a users email address and it still doesn't work.

Here is my code for the component (email address changed for privacy reasons):

```
<PeoplePicker defaultSelectedUsers={['user@domain.com']} selectionMode="single" selectionChanged={handleSelectionChanged}></PeoplePicker>
```

No matter what I do it is not prepopulating with a user / person.

The permissions are all there (I think) which is proven by the component working when I start typing a user name.

Any ideas what I might be missing?

As always thanks so much for any input in advance.

----- edit ----

Oh okay, it seems that I can't use that prop with mgt-react? I have to use defultSelectedUserIds and can't just provide an email address. Can someone confirm this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there mgt [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/people-picker) for the `defaultSelectedUsers` property? As far as I am aware, the people picker only supports `defaultSelectedUsersById`. The email address should work though, assuming the graph is able to retrieve the users (it's their actual id).

For a quick test, are you able to retrieve the users through the [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) with the `/users/${id}` (replace id with your email) filter? This is what we use for the property.

Comment: Yep you're dead right, the email address works, I guess I just got the wrong property. Thanks so much.

I can't find any reference to the property I was using...oops!

Comment: No worries, I was just trying to find the reference if there was one! Glad to hear its working as expected!